# How to return value to Entry Widget

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I don't know how to return or print result to entry widget. I've tried to add code on the res function, but it still doesn't return the result that I want.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Test")
win.configure(background='black')

enternumber = Label(win, text="Enter Number")
enternumber.grid(column=0, row=0)

var1 = IntVar()
txtenternumber = Entry(win, width=20, textvariable=var1)
txtenternumber.grid(column=1, row=0)

enternumber = Label(win, text="Enter Number")
enternumber.grid(column=0, row=1)

var2 = IntVar()
txtenternumber = Entry(win, width=20, textvariable=var2)
txtenternumber.grid(column=1, row=1)

def res():
    result = var1.get()*var2.get()
    #here the code i added
    resultentry.bind('<Return>', res)

#Here the button should returning result
resultbutton = Button(win, text="Ok", command=res)
resultbutton.grid(column=2, row=2)

resultlabel = Label(win,text="Result")
resultlabel.grid(column=0, row=2)

#I want result printed here
resultentry = Entry(win, width=30)
resultentry.grid(column=1,row=2)
```

Comment: under your def res() function you just need to add: resultentry.insert(0,result)                             This is also a good resource for tkinter: https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Test")
win.configure(background='black')

enternumber = Label(win, text="Enter Number")
enternumber.grid(column=0, row=0)

var1 = IntVar()
txtenternumber = Entry(win, width=20, textvariable=var1)
txtenternumber.grid(column=1, row=0)

enternumber = Label(win, text="Enter Number")
enternumber.grid(column=0, row=1)

var2 = IntVar()
txtenternumber = Entry(win, width=20, textvariable=var2)
txtenternumber.grid(column=1, row=1)

def res():
   result = var1.get()*var2.get()
   resultentry.insert(0,result)  # INSERTS RESULT INTO resultentry
   resultentry.bind('<Return>', res)

resultbutton = Button(win, text="Ok", command=res)
resultbutton.grid(column=2, row=2)

resultlabel = Label(win,text="Result")
resultlabel.grid(column=0, row=2)

resultentry = Entry(win, width=30)
resultentry.grid(column=1,row=2)

win.mainloop()
```

Sorry, forgot to add this. Yes, you just need to use resultentry.insert(0, result)and you should be set. I also like using this as a good resource:
https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Comment: copy explanation from your comment to your answer. And you could format code - like in question -  to make it more readable

Comment: This answer would be much better with an explanation. Otherwise we have to compare the code line by line and character by character to find what is different.

Comment: Sorry, everyone, I made the edits to the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: i added this code "resultentry.delete(0, END)" in res definiton. and deleted this line "resultentry.bind('<Return>', res)" because i think it's useless

Comment: It's just where you have resultentry.bind('<Return>', res). If you moved it out of the Res function, then it should work.